# How do I replace <NA> by a value

Tags: r

I want to create a binary variable about people being interested in professional practices. I did so with the different options, but I can't seem to find a way to attribute the value 0  to  observations. Does someone know how?

```
ECEMD <-
  ECEMD %>%
  mutate(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2 = case_when(
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Did not participate" ~ 0,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Not applicable" ~ 0,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Excellent" ~ 1,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Poor" ~ 1,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Fair" ~ 1,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Good" ~ 1,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == "Very good" ~ 1, 
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM == NA ~ 0))
freq(ECEMD$PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2)
```

UPDATE:

Okay, I tried

```
ECEMD <-
  ECEMD %>%
  mutate(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2 = case_when(
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM %in% c("Did not participate",
                                       "Not applicable",
                                       NA) ~ 0, 
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM %in% c("Excellent",
                                          "Poor",
                                          "Fair",
                                          "Good",
                                          "Very good") ~ 1))
```

But the NA are still not changed to 0. What do?

Comment: Can't use `==` to detect `NA` values because they may or may not be equal. Use `is.na()`.

Comment: An alternative to the canonical `is.na(.)` in the answer below is to replace `==` with `%in%`, which does allow `NA`. (It is not as efficient, certainly, but it provides a different path, that's all.)

Comment: in order to do any more debugging we're going to need a [mcve]. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ...

Answer (score 1):

probably

```
is.na(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM) ~ 0
```

(a reproducible example would be nice ...)

`NA` handling is in general very tricky. You might even want to put this clause *first*, so that all the equality clauses don't get messed up by `NA` values (because `x == NA` is `NA`, not `TRUE` or `FALSE`, for all values ...)

The fourth example in `?case_when` actually discusses this issue explicitly:

> Note that NA values in the vector x do not get special treatment. If you want to explicitly handle NA values you can use the `is.na` function

As mentioned by @r2evans, using `%in%` could work too:

```r
mutate(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2 = case_when(
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM %in% c("Did not participate",
                                      "Not applicable",
                                      NA) ~ 0,
    PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM %in% c("Excellent" ,
                                      "Poor",
                                      "Fair",
                                      "Good",
                                      "Very good") ~ 1
   )
```

or perhaps even

```r
mutate(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2 =  
     ifelse(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_DIM %in% c("Did not participate",
                                              "Not applicable",
                                              NA),
    0, 1))
```

Comment: When I tried


ECEMD <-
  ECEMD %>%
is.na(PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2) ~ 0

freq(ECEMD$PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2)


It says :
Error in freq(ECEMD$PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2) : 
  ECEMD$PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2 is either NULL or does not exist

Comment: it doesn't look like you included the `mutate()` ? my first suggestion is meant to be incorporated into your `case_when` statement, not as a standalone solution

Comment: I did try with %in% now, but still <NA> won't change.

Also, I am not sure how to integrate mutate() with the formula you gave with (is.na)

Answer (score 0):

OKAY! I found the answer. I used

```
ECEMD$PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2[is.na(ECEMD$PROFSKILL_PROFPRACTICE_INDICE2)] <- 0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).